# UICollectionViewCell pushed down when embedded in navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm working on an app on which there is a view which has a UICollectionView inside of it.
Normally it would work just fine, however the moment I embedded it into a navigation controller, for some reason the cells were pushed down about a row instead of starting at the top of the view, see below.

[image: UICollectionViewCell spacing]

Is there a way to make it stick to the top instead of being pushed down?

Edit: The insets were the problem as both comments mentioned, removing the automatic adjustment fixed it!

Comment: That should not happen, check the top section inset of your collection view.

Comment: Try setting `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` on the view controller that contains your collection view.

Answer (score 0):

The insets were the problem as both comments mentioned, removing the automatic adjustment fixed it!